# Nullpointer exception after running kubectl and helm command in Jenkinsfile

Tags: shell, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to run `kubernetes` and `helm` command in the deploy step of the `Jenkinsfile` but I am facing Nullpointer exception. Below is my code:

```
stage ('Create and Deploy to k8s Dev Environment') {
            //agent {label 'docker-maven-slave'}
            options {
                skipDefaultCheckout()
            }
            steps {
                withCredentials([string(credentialsId: K8S_DEV_SECRET_ID)]) {
                    command """

                    kubectl apply --server=https://10.0.0.0:443 --insecure-skip-tls-verify=false --namespace: "dev-ns" -f -

                    helm template -f "portal-chart/deploy/values-dev.yaml" portal-chart
                    """
                }
}
```

Below are the logs:

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: com.xxx.jenkins.pipeline.library.utils.dispatch.ShellCommandException: Exception calling shell command, 'kubectl apply ... ': null
    at command.call(command.groovy:51)
```

Comment: Such an exception (instead of a reasonable error message) is nearly always a bug in the Java program causing the exception. Maybe you want to file a bug report against kubernetes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. Below is the code:

```
stage ('Create and Deploy to k8s Dev Environment') {
            //agent {label 'docker-maven-slave'}
            options {
                skipDefaultCheckout()
            }
            steps {
                    command """

                    kubectl apply --server=https://10.0.0.0:443 --insecure-skip-tls-verify=false --namespace: "dev-ns" -f -

                    helm template -f "portal-chart/deploy/values-dev.yaml" portal-chart
                    """
                
}
```